# Error in test when mocking service with Observable (Angular 2)

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, observable

I have a component that uses a service that returns an Observable.  Instead of wiring up this service in my Jasmine test, I've chosen to spy on a mock.

Here is the NumProbesService [numprobes.service.ts] that uses Http to get a JSON response from a web server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {ProbeCount} from "./probecount.model";

@Injectable()
export class NumProbesService {

  private numProbesUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/getnumberofprobes';
  private probeCount: ProbeCount;

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('X-Auth-Key', 'mjones');
    headers.append('X-Auth-Secret', '111111-2222222-22222-3233-4444444');
  }


  public getProbeCount() : Observable<ProbeCount> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

    return this.http.get(this.numProbesUrl, {headers: headers})
      .map((response:Response) =>  this.probeCount = <ProbeCount>response.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

}
```

I'm mocking this service up with NumProbesMockService [numprobes.service.mock.ts]:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ProbeInfo } from './probeinfo.model';

export class NumProbesMockService {

  probeInfo : ProbeInfo = new ProbeInfo(3);

  public getProbeCount(): Observable<ProbeInfo> {
    return Observable.of(this.probeInfo);
  }

}
```

The ProbeInfo [probeinfo.model.ts] class is here:

```
export class ProbeInfo {

  private online : boolean;
  private accepted: boolean;
  private probeCount: number;

  constructor(probeCount: number) {

  }

}
```

The component that I'm testing is here:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {NumProbesService} from './numprobes.service';
import {ProbeCount} from "./probecount.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'numprobes-box',
  templateUrl: './numprobes.component.html'
})
export class NumProbesComponent {

  name: string;
  numprobes: number;
  probeCount: ProbeCount;

  constructor(private numProbesService: NumProbesService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = "Number of Probes";

    this.numProbesService.getProbeCount().subscribe(
      (probeCount) => {
        console.log("probeCount: " + JSON.stringify(probeCount));
        console.log(probeCount.total_probe_count);
        this.numprobes = probeCount.total_probe_count;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the actual test for the component.

```
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {DebugElement} from '@angular/core';

import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {NumProbesService} from './numprobes.service';
import {NumProbesMockService} from './numprobes.service.mock';
import {NumProbesComponent} from './numprobes.component';
import {ProbeInfo} from './probeinfo.model';


describe('NumProbesComponent', () => {

  let comp: NumProbesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NumProbesComponent>;
  let spy: jasmine.Spy;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let numProbesService: NumProbesService; // the actually injected service

  const numProbes = 5;
  let probeInfo : ProbeInfo = new ProbeInfo(numProbes);


  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NumProbesComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NumProbesService, useClass: NumProbesMockService }
      ]
    });


    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NumProbesComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    numProbesService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NumProbesService);

    spy = spyOn(numProbesService, 'getProbeCount')
      .and.returnValue(probeInfo);
  });

  it('Should show the label within component', () => {

    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info-box-text"));
    el = de.nativeElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toBe('Number of Probes', 'Label displayed');

  });


  it('should show the name of the info box, "Number of Probes"', () => {

    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info-box-number"));
    el = de.nativeElement;

    console.log("el.textContent: " + el.textContent);

    expect(el).toBeDefined();
    expect(el.textContent).toBe('', 'nothing displayed');

    let probeInfoCalled = numProbesService.getProbeCount();

    expect(spy.calls.any()).toBe(true, 'getProbeCount not yet called');

  });
}
```

So that brings me to the problem.  One of my tests is failing.  After fixture.detectChange() it looks like the component is initialized and the getProbeCount() is executed on the mock service, NumProbesMockService.

It says `this.numProbesService.getProbeCount(...).subscribe is not a function`.  How could that be?  this.numProbesService.getProbeCount() returns an Observable which has a subscribe method, right?

Here is the complete error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) NumProbesComponent Should show the label within component FAILED
    Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: this.numProbesService.getProbeCount(...).subscribe is not a function
        at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:811:0 <- src/test.ts:106351:33)
        at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js:26:0 <- src/test.ts:6476:16)
        at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js:88:0 <- src/test.ts:6538:16)
        at new ViewWrappedError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/errors.js:73:0 <- src/test.ts:60069:16)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:650:0 <- src/test.ts:84195:23)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:623:0 <- src/test.ts:84168:18)
        at ViewRef_.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:179:0 <- src/test.ts:61015:20)
        at ComponentFixture._tick (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:191:0 <- src/test.ts:12899:36)
        at webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:205:45 <- src/test.ts:12913:53
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:0 <- src/test.ts:105782:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:71475:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:0 <- src/test.ts:105781:32)
        at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:269:0 <- src/test.ts:31712:37)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:0 <- src/test.ts:105781:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- src/test.ts:105653:43)
```

Comment: What do you see if you console.log `numProbesService.getProbeCount` right before subscribing? Side note: seems like your spy AND the mock are doing the same thing TWICE: since your mock is already returning mock data, why do you need to spy to also return mock data?

Comment: @AngularFrance, I added `console.log(this.numProbesService.getProbeCount());` to the component just before the call to subscribe() and got `LOG: ProbeInfo{}`.  Does this mean that I'm not getting an Observable back from my mock service when getProbeCount() is called?    The method clearly returns `Observable<ProbeInfo>` though.  Do you see where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me what you're trying to validate in your test? (without mentioning HOW you're trying to do it, I'm interested in knowing WHAT you're trying to do)

Comment: @AngularFrance, I'm trying to verify that 1) the label for the info box that is a property of the component appears in the info box html and 2) that the number of probes (a property of the ProbeCount object) matches the number returned by the mock service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you get is due to the **spy overriding the original method**.

In other words, after this line is executed:

```ts
spyOn(numProbesService, 'getProbeCount')
```

`numProbesService.getProbeCount` no longer references your original method which returns an Observable, it references the spy.

I set up a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ehpj1OU7tXX7Lq6oRqKE?p=preview) to test my answer and it works as expected: if you comment out the spy, you'll be able to subscribe again:

```ts
// app.component.spec.ts

beforeEach( async(() => {
  ps = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProbesService);

  // The spy overrides the ps.getProbeCount() method.
  //spyOn(ps, 'getProbeCount');

  // trigger initial data binding
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should return 5', (done) => {
  // This will NOT work if the spy has been set up.
  ps.getProbeCount().subscribe(val => {
    expect(val).toEqual(5);
    done();
  });
});

it('should have been called', () => {
  // This will work ONLY IF the spy has been set up.
  expect(ps.getProbeCount).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But like I said in the comment, you're **doing the same thing twice**. Either use the spy OR the mock to return the mock value, but not both.

Comment: Yes indeed!  That did it.  I was both spying and mocking and I should do one or the other.  I got rid of the spy and just used the mock and everything works fine.

Comment: Great. If you don't mind, please mark the answer as "correct" so other people on StackOverflow can use it in the future. Thanks, Melvin!